# Identify unique user in Dialogflow V1

Tags: telegram-bot, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, api-ai

So I am testing out Dialogflow and one of the first questions I have is: how does my bot know who it is talking to? I need to identify a user and keep that information for as long as I can. The basic scenario being:

1. User starts his/her first conversation.
2. Chatbot send a fulfillment request to the server trying to match a user within its own database.
3. The user is found, the information (as a JWT or some other token) is sent back to Dialogflow and stored there for further communication. In reality, this part would involve asking for user email, sending a verification code to that email and then verifying the user with the code.
4. User then starts chatting with a bot and all fulfillment requests get the unique token stored for this very user, so that my REST API knows which user is being served with the response.

Couldn't find anything about it in the docs (maybe I am looking in the wrong places).

There will be several integrations, like Messenger, Viber, Telegram. I dunno, maybe those APIs add some unique information on the user?...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you find the solution for this question

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I know it's been a while, but maybe this will help someone else.

1. The right solution here is a user id, not a session id. A user id is provided by the chat platform (Facebook, Slack etc) and is consistent across sessions for the same user.

To get the user id, go to the Fulfillment tab, enable the editor and use a function like so:

```
let r = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest
//this makes sure that you're on an integration 
if (r["source"]){
     return r.payload.data.sender.id; 
 }
```

2. To tie together ids from different platforms, you probably have to have some kind of log-in process every time you encounter a new id on a platform.

Answer (score 1):

Pop,

Sessions are built in already into DialogFlow requests to your fulfilment service, if you check the payload you will find a sessionId, it remains the same for the same client until it expires.

However if you want to identify the user from any of the clients that you can connect to DialogFlow like Messenger then from the same request payload to you you will notice that there is an object named **originalRequest** that is only available when requests are coming from those clients.

You can personalize those users response eg [using their FB firstname in a message to them](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity).